# Envolver div generado por PHP con otro div con clase CSS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Mi pregunta es acerca de lo siguiente. Ahora tengo esto en un archivo .php:

```
<div class="uno">
   <?php if( function_exists('number') ) { number('tres'); ?>
</div>
```

El código PHP que está en el medio genera un `<div class="tres">`, así:

```
<div class="uno">
   <div class="tres"></div>
</div>
```

Pues bien, lo que busco es: si se genera el `<div class="tres">`, que éste quede envuelto con otro `<div>` con una clase CSS. El resultado debería ser este:

```
<div class="uno">
   <div class="dos"> ← La "envoltura" que necesito
      <div class="tres"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

No puedo poner el `<div class="dos">` directamente en mi archivo .php, por eso necesito que aparezca únicamente si está el `<div class="tres">`.

¿Se puede hacer esto con JavaScript? ¿Cómo?

Comment: ¿El `<div class="tres">` no está cerrado?

Comment: Sí, lo está. Olvidé eso :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer lo que deseas debes comprobar si existe el selector '`div.uno div.tres`' (un `<div>` con clase `uno` que tiene un hijo que es un `<div>` con clase tres) haciendo uso de [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) y si es así crear el `<div>` con [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) y cambiarle la clase a `dos` con [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) y por último hacer el cambio de nodos con [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) y [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild):

```html
<div class="uno">
   <div class="tres">hola</div>
</div>
<script>
let tres = document.querySelector('div.uno div.tres');
/* ¿Existe el selector deseado? */
if (tres !== null) {
  /* Obtenemos el div padre */
  let uno = tres.parentNode;
  /* Creamos un nuevo elemento div */
  let dos = document.createElement('div');
  /* Le cambiamos la clase a "dos" */
  dos.setAttribute('class', 'dos');
  /* Quitamos el nodo tres como hijo del uno */
  uno.removeChild(tres);
  /* Agregamos como hijo de uno al dos */
  uno.appendChild(dos);
  /* Agregamos como hijo del dos al tres */
  dos.appendChild(tres);
}
/* Mostramos el resultado final */
console.log(document.querySelector('div.uno').outerHTML);
</script>
```

Comment: Era lo que buscaba. Gracias!